# PHP code to fill dropdown list in append function jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a button when user click on that button it appends a dropdown list to the HTML and I have used PHP to retrieve data from database in fill the dropdown list, while i try this code it is not working for me! any idea?

```
    $(".pageSheet").on("click", ".bt2", function () {
       $(this).closest(".pageIn").append("<p>Image: <select name='image'>
<?php include'scripts/addImage.php'; addImg(); ?></select><br><button class='deleteCon'>Delete</button></p>"); i++;});
```

Comment: What does this code do (according to your expectations)?

Comment: Server side scripts don't run inside client scripts. They output the response and they are done. Use ajax to make new requests to server. You may be the 1 billionth person to post this type of question, I think it should required reading before posting any questions tagged with php and anything JavaScript related.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot append `<?php // code here ?>` to an already rendered webpage using JavaScript and expect PHP to parse it. PHP parses the page while it is being handled by the webserver attending to the request. If you want JavaScript (client-side) to interact with something PHP generates from a Database (server-side), you need to look into [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I really don't mean to take it out on the OP, but some version of this question is asked  dozens of times every day. We need a really solid and thorough wiki post on this and we need to mark all variants of this question as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I have searched for this situation anthony.. coz I have already have another page that same php in jQuery scripts it works fine.. but this one does not work.. I consider ur point before I ask!!

Comment: You definitely don't have any PHP code like you posted working. It's simply not the way PHP works. You may have set a variable in some JavaScript like `var something = '<?php echo $something_else; ?>';`, but what you tried will never work.